# What is the right Windows API call to view and kill a task on a remote computer?

Tags: winapi

From the command line, I can **list** tasks on a remote machine like this:

```
c:\>tasklist /s some_machine /u admin_user /p admin_user_password

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
System Idle Process              0                            0         16 K
System                           4                            0        236 K
svchost.exe                    632                            0      3,328 K
svchost.exe                    700                            0      4,660 K
svchost.exe                    776                            0     38,664 K
```

And I can **kill** them like this:

```
c:\>taskkill /s some_machine /im notepad.exe /f /u admin_user /p admin_password
SUCCESS: The process "notepad.exe" with PID 1828 has been terminated.
```

How can I do this using Win32 API calls?  I'm trying to implement this in Delphi, but I am happy to translate an example from another language.

I've been looking at [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28VS.85%29.aspx), which works great for a local machine, but does not seem to support remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this via [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do it [with WMI](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/wmi_process_stop.htm).  Specifically, [Win32_Process.Terminate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393907%28VS.85%29.aspx).